# How do the scale of an embedding affects a downstream task?

Tags: computer-vision, embeddings, self-supervised-learning

I am currently training a neural network in a self-supervised fashion, using Contrastive Loss and I want to use that network then to fine-tune it in a classification task with a small fraction of the data with labels. I'm basing this project on the paper titled [A Simple Framework for Contrastive Learning of Visual Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709)
by *Ting Chen et al*.

My questions go oriented on a very specific thing that I think is causing me some problems. After finishing the self-supervised training I extract the embeddings of a bunch of data and I get the following. These stats are calculated using a flattening of all the embedding of all the bunch of data.

```
Mean: -23.090446
Std: 91.78753
Min: -710.24493
Max: 651.8682
```

What bugs me is that when I extract the embeddings in a ResNet, for example, I get much much lower values (the highest value in absolute terms don't usually go beyond 15), but I'm getting much larger values.

When looking for similarities with the use of these embeddings, it is something that looks like it works, but my question is that if it is something that might affect when adding another layer and using it for a classification task.

I have the feeling that something here is wrong but I can not spot exactly what it is.

Could you give me any advice on this?